# Using PHP, how do I append a JSON blob to an existing multi-level JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am attempting to get some JSON data from an external file and append some user generated JSON to it that gets sent via `GET`. In this example I have removed the `GET` business and supplied the new JSON as a variable.

The old data is coming from `data/test.json` and is stored in the variable `$oldData`.

The new data will be coming from a `GET`, but in this test it is in the variable `$newData`

---

Here is the JSON from `data/test.json`

```
{
    "monkeys": [
        {
            "id": 1424634259848,
            "name": "Funky Monkey",
            "description": "This sure is a funky monkey!",
            "favoriteFoods": [
                "bananas",
                "cheese"
            ],
            "image": "img/funky-monkey.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the PHP that has gotten me this far

```
$fileData = file_get_contents('data/test.json');
$oldData = json_decode($fileData, true);

$newData = json_decode('{"id": 1424634259848,"name": "Monkey Ball","description": "This is a video game, not a monkey!","favoriteFoods": ["bits","pixels"],"image": "img/monkey-ball.jpg"}', true);
$result = array_merge_recursive($oldData,$newData);

echo '<pre>' . print_r(json_encode($result), true) . '</pre>';
```

Here is the result

```
{
    "monkeys": [
        {
            "id": 1424634259848,
            "name": "Funky Monkey",
            "description": "This sure is a funky monkey!",
            "favoriteFoods": [
                "bananas",
                "cheese"
            ],
            "image": "img/funky-monkey.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "id": 1424634259848,
    "name": "Monkey Ball",
    "description": "This is a video game, not a monkey!",
    "favoriteFoods": [
        "bits",
        "pixels"
    ],
    "image": "img/monkey-ball.jpg"
}
```

Unfortunately the second monkey is outside the brackets and not the second item in the monkeys array.

Here is the result I would like

```
{
    "monkeys": [
        {
            "id": 1424634259848,
            "name": "Funky Monkey",
            "description": "This sure is a funky monkey!",
            "favoriteFoods": [
                "bananas",
                "cheese"
            ],
            "image": "img/funky-monkey.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 1424634259848,
            "name": "Monkey Ball",
            "description": "This is a video game, not a monkey!",
            "favoriteFoods": [
                "bits",
                "pixels"
            ],
            "image": "img/monkey-ball.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't care about keys or values of the JSON, I just want to append that new JSON blob as the next index under `monkey`.

So, long question short, using PHP how do I append that blob to the end of a multi-level JSON object?

Also, I appreciate that there are many similar questions on stack**overflow** and perhaps I missed one that covers this topic. If you know of a question that covers this, please comment with the link.

Comment: Is the `monkeys` key always the same? Or does it change? Will the JSON file always be a nested set of values and always have one key, or can it vary?

Comment: Yes, the `monkeys` key will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
<?php

     $json = '{
    "monkeys": [
        {
            "id": 1424634259848,
            "name": "Funky Monkey",
            "description": "This sure is a funky monkey!",
            "favoriteFoods": [
                "bananas",
                "cheese"
            ],
            "image": "img/funky-monkey.jpg"
        }
    ]
}';
    $jsonArray = json_decode($json,true);
    $newJson = '{"id": 1424634259848,"name": "Monkey Ball","description": "This is a video game, not a monkey!","favoriteFoods": ["bits","pixels"],"image": "img/monkey-ball.jpg"}';
    $newJson = json_decode($newJson,true);
    $jsonArray['monkeys'][] = $newJson;
    $ultimateJson = json_encode($jsonArray);
    var_dump($ultimateJson);
```

You are combining both arrays instead of appending one array to another.
http://codepad.viper-7.com/Uy3Zbn

Answer (score 1):

You want to push the new array onto the `monkeys` element of the old array:

```
$oldData['monkeys'][] = $newData;
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, looks like that's right along the lines of what **Royalty** did above.